# Why does my for loop to disable buttons not work, but the same loop works for setting colors in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jframe, jbutton

I am programming a TicTacToe game and I want to use a for loop with my `JButton` components inside them like this:

```
private void clearField(){
    for (int i = 0; i<PlayField.length; i++){
        PlayField[i].setText("");
        PlayField[i].setBackground(new Color(41,200,193));
    }
}
```

Playfield in this example is an Array with all my nine buttons, that loop works but this one doesn't:

```
private void setInvis(){
    for (int i = 0; i<PlayField.length; i++){
        PlayField[i].setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: In a game, we should not be changing the components in the GUI, but instead of changing their state, the color, text or icon for example, to indicate the current state held by a *game model*.

Comment: BTW *"for loop to disable buttons"* It is quite possible to disable buttons in a visible GUI, but that's not what the code above is doing. To ***disable** the buttons*, use `PlayField[i].setEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in a previous comment, `JButton.setVisible(false);` only changes the user's ability to see the component. In the eyes of the frame itself, the component is still there. If this is what you want, and it still doesn't work, you may have to call `JFrame.revalidate();` after changing the state of the button. This method essentially 'refreshes' the frame whenever you add components or change them. [See more here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate--)

If your goal is to make the buttons visible, but disable them, use `JButton.setVisible(false);`.